# Htaccess - point multiple domain to different path

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, .htaccess

For example I have a domain `example.com` and server IP of `12.34.56.78`

I need to point `example.com` to a facebook page, then point `12.34.56.78`to my root directory where my website files are saved.

Here's my current Htaccess code

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.facebook.com/examplefbpage/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^12.34.56.78$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Currently, both `example.com` and `12.34.56.78` redirects to the facebook page.

By the way, my site a created using wordpress.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is probably not the correct way to accomplish this (firstly having a site display by requesting the IP is not all that user-friendly if that's how users will access the site) and secondly if you have access to the Apache config files that is a better place to set the redirect. Essentially you should have a 'vhost' for the domain that does a redirect to the facebook page and a separate 'vhost' for the IP address. You would set the `servername` property of the vhost to state what is served whenever a request comes in to that name. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: @WilliamPatton Thanks for that. I tried to remove the 'RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^12.34.56.78$' and it works, weird :( ... For now my site is not yet configured as vhost, i'll change it to that when the time permits.. thanks :)

Comment: not a problem @Katherine, glad that I was able to help you out a little :)